# Can someone help me with this compare array?

Tags: c, new-operator

Im new to C and am having trouble with this code i'm writing. I'm almost 100% sure its because of my compare array section but I don't really know what to change. Can anyone help? If you would need my entire code I can also post that.
The code should compare letters entered by the user with words in a .txt document and see if you can spell any words with those letters.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 99
#define NUM_WORDS 100

void find_frequency(char string[], int count[]);
int compare_arrays(int dictionary[], int user[]);

int main()
{
    int total_words=11; //number of words
    char dictionary_words[NUM_WORDS][SIZE]; //store words in directory
    FILE *cfPtr; //dictionary.txt pointer

    if ((cfPtr=fopen("dictionary.txt","r"))==NULL)//try to open file
    {
        puts("File dictionary.txt could not be opened.");
        exit(1);//exit if file doesn't open
    }

    else{ //Read each word from the dictionary and save to array
        char line[SIZE]; //save each word

        {
            while(fgets(line,SIZE,cfPtr)!= NULL)
                  {
                      char*tokenPtr=strtok(line, "\t");
                      while(tokenPtr != NULL)
                        {
                            strcpy(dictionary_words[total_words],tokenPtr);
                            total_words++;
                            tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, "\t" );
                        }

                  }
        }
        }
    fclose(cfPtr);//close file

    char string[11];//get string of characters from user
    int count[26]={0};//store the number of each letter

    printf("Enter letters:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);


    find_frequency(string, count);//count of each character entered

    char temp[SIZE];
    int temp_count[26]={0};//convert words into letters
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=total_words; i++);
    {
        strcpy(temp,dictionary_words[i]);
        find_frequency(temp,temp_count);//convert word to letters in alphabet

        if (compare_arrays(temp_count,count))//compare words with letters entered
        {
            printf("%s:", temp);//print what you can spell
        }
        else
        {
             printf("broken", temp);
        }
       memset(temp_count,0,sizeof(temp_count));//test next word
    }
    return(0);
}//end main

//define function
void find_frequency(char string[],int count[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z')
        {
            count[string[i]-'a']++;
        }
    }
}

int compare_arrays(int dictionary[], int user[])
{
    int j = 0;

    while (user[j] >= dictionary[j])
    {
        j++;
        if (j == 26)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("also broken");
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: We can't read your mind and figure out what the code is supposed to do. Please add more explanation.

Comment: This looks as if you wanted a loop (`while`) and a condition (`if`), but you have two conditoions here. Otherwise, how do you expect `j` to get to 26?

Comment: @chrisjn  How do you want to compare the arrays? Do you want to check whether they are equal or that the first one is not less than the second one?

Comment: I suppose you need a `while` loop instead of a `if`, something like `while user[j] >=  dirctionary[j]`.

Comment: A rather verbose way of writing `return 1;`...

Comment: This code is to compare letters entered with words in a document and it should spit out what words you can spell. My issue is that the code isn't printing anything no matter what I enter.

Comment: "code isn't printing anything"  --> There are no output functions in the posted code.  Why expect it to print anything?  "no matter what I enter" -->  There are no input functions in the posted code either.

Comment: @chrisjn: Your question is not clear. So do one thing. Give one or two examples and tell us what are the expected outputs.

Comment: @chrisjn now we need a minimal dictionary.txt file and an example of input expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning wrong result.

```
int compare_arrays(int dictionary[], int user[])
{
    int j = 0;

    while (user[j] >= dictionary[j])
    {
        j++;
        if (j == 26)
        {
            // You have checked all 26 letters and for all of them condition is true. Therefore a word can be made from user entered letters.
            return 1; 
        }
    }
    return 0; //Word can not be made from user entered letters
}
```

If you want to take care of case sensitivity,

```
void find_frequency(char string[],int count[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        //If letter is in upper case, it will be converted to lower case before checking.
        if (tolower(string[i]) >= 'a' && tolower(string[i]) <= 'z')
        {
            count[tolower(string[i])-'a']++;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Error in tokenizing.
1) `int total_words=11; //number of words`
    You are using this variable as array index. So it should be initialized to zero. Or you declare another variable for index.
   `int index=0;`

2) strtok will return address of start of token. So you are writing words with token and not copying null terminator.

```
    char *prevTokenPtr = line;
    while(fgets(line,SIZE,cfPtr)!= NULL)
    {
        char*tokenPtr=strtok(line, "\t");
        while(tokenPtr != NULL)
        {
            /* Copy from last token to this token. */
            int lengthToCopy = (tokenPtr  - prevTokenPtr)/sizeof(char);
            strncpy(dictionary_words[index], prevTokenPtr, lengthToCopy);
            dictionary_words[index][lengthToCopy] = '\0';

            printf("dictionary_words[%d] is [%s]\n", index, dictionary_words[index]);
            index++;

            prevTokenPtr = tokenPtr + 1; //Neglect '\t'
            tokenPtr     = strtok(NULL, "\t" );
        }

        /* Copy the last word. */
        if(NULL != prevTokenPtr)
        {
            strcpy(dictionary_words[index], prevTokenPtr);
            printf("dictionary_words[%d] is [%s]\n", index, dictionary_words[index]);
            index++;
        }
  }
```

Please note:

1) I assume the input is like this.
"word1"\t"word2"\t"word3"\t...\t"wordN"

2) I have not tested this code. Prints should help you debugging further.

Comment: After editing that in my code. I'm still getting the same results, After I enter some letters that I know should spell something all I get back is a " : "

Comment: @chrisjn This could be some other issue. (1) Print temp before and after calling find_frequency() and make sure it is correct. (2) Print dictionary_words[i] with temp and make sure that is also correct. (3) You have declared `char string[11];`. Make sure you are not entering more than 10 characters. Better do `scanf("%10s", string); string[10]='\0';` Try with these changes and let me know your observation.

Comment: I added those print temp commands with a \n so they would be printed onto different lines but all they print are blank lines. I tried printing the dictionary_words[i] and i also just got a blank line. Why would it be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is the correct answer as it's hard to guess what you are actually trying to do, but you probably want this, or something similar:

```
int compare_arrays(int dictionary[], int user[])
{
    int j = 0;

    while (user[j] >= dictionary[j])
    {
        j++;
        if (j == 26)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still getting the same issue. I should have probably posted what exactly my issue was when I asked the question. The issue is no matter what I enter nothing gets printed. I decided to add an 'else' statement in my compare arrays and it keeps printing what I wrote in the 'else'.

Comment: @chrisjn you need to provide more information, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Posted my entire code. The code should promp the user for a series of letters. Than read in the letters and print out which dictionary words can be made from the letters you enter. My problem is whenever I would enter anything I wouldn't get anything back. I put an extra line into where I compare the arrays to see if its working and it doesn't seem to be. Its keeps printing out the "also broken" line I added in.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried printing the dictionary_words[i] and i also just got a blank line. Why would it be doing this?

A small, but momentous error:

```
    for(i=0; i<=total_words; i++);
    {
        …
```

The `;` at the end of the `for` line causes the block which was supposed to be the loop body to be executed only once, with a wrong `i`.

Comment: Also `i<=total_words` has a *bad smell* :)